# Procedure to decode the machine code into the assembly instructions

Tags: java, assembly, decode, machine-code

I had given in an assignment with machine code as:

```
3c011001
34300000
8e080000
20090003
11200004
01094020
2129ffff
ae080000
08100004
2002000a
0000000c
```

and I need to decode these to get the assembly instructions as:

```
lui  $at, 0x1001
ori  $s0, $at, 0x0000
lw   $t0, 0($s0)
addi $t1, $zero, 3
beq  $t1, $zero, 0x0004
add  $t0, $t0, $t1
addi $t1, $t1, -1
sw   $t0, 0($s0)
j    0x00400010
addi $v0, $zero, 10
syscall
```

What is procedure here in decoding?

I tried a java program to covert the hexa values in to binary and based on MIPS encoding I used switch case on binary values and I came with the output as:

```
0011 1100 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0001 lui     $at, 0x1001
0011 0100 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ori     $s0, $at, 0x0000
1000 1110 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 lw      $t0, 0($s0)
0010 0000 0000 1001 0000 0000 0000 0011 addi    $t1, $zero, 3
0001 0001 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 beq     $zero, $t1
0000 0001 0000 1001 0100 0000 0010 0000 add     $t1, $t0, 0x4020
0010 0001 0010 1001 1111 1111 1111 1111 addi    $t1, $t1, 0x15151515
1010 1110 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 sw      $t0, 0($s0)
0000 1000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 j       0x0004
0010 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 1010 addi    $v0, $zero, 0x00010
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 syscall
```

Comment: This looks like MIPS assembly; I wrote a similar program in Python, and I essentially mapped the opcode/function code to a specific instruction name.  You can do the same in Java with a `Map`.

Comment: @JacobG. I have almost done with java may this may entire change in the code

Comment: Well, your `switch` seems to be working well for the opcodes, so there's no pressing reason to abandon it at this late stage,  So your _real_ problem  is with decoding the **operands**, then?

Comment: 1111 is 15 in decimal, F in hexadecimal, not 15 in hexadecimal

Comment: @harold Then how do I do it

Comment: @KevinAnderson is there any solution

Comment: Well what I'd do is take the instruction as an `int` and just chop off the immediate part eg `(short)instruction`. Then convert that to a string by printing it. That uses that the immediate is sign extended .. which isn't always true, for eg `ori` it would have to chopped like `instruction & 0xFFFF`

Comment: @harold I did'nt get you completely. What I understood is to split the opcode from the binary isn't it

Comment: Perhaps but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Actually can you show some of the decoding now so it's easier to talk about it in relation to your code?

Comment: @harold Please could give me little more explaination on chopping